# Phonegap Build InAppBrowser for cli-5.2.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I want to use the InAppBrowser in my App build with Phonegap Build.
I am using cli-5.2.0. So I included the following plugin:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/673

```
<gap:plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" version="0.1" />
```

But when I build the app I get the following error:

> Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >=
>   4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: InAppBrowser.java - You can fix this here

Clicking the 'fix this here' link brings me to a 404 page.

Does anyone know how to use the plugins in my phonegap version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to specify the source. So this here works:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** 2015-02-10 If you are reading this now, you should be using [the example given by almo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33485209/3255670)

@aimo,
The "core" plugins are difficult to find because, the link to them is hidden.

If you go to this page, you *cannot* see the *core* plugin
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins
but here you can
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/core
It is a bad interface issue.

Your XML element would be:
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2">`

However, we are moving to NPM as our source, so you should source the latest from [NPM here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html)

Your core plugins are [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html). Your new plugin would look like this
`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser " version="1.0.1">`

You can get additional information at:
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
**11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

Comment: You should have supplied the exact solution/alternative if you could, not "would look like this". I also have this issue now, and your answer has not been helpful.

Comment: @tormuto, I don't know what you are talking about I have give the person asking the question two possible solutions. Perhaps you are not familiar with how the plugin system works.

Comment: Both of the options didn't work (i suggest you try them out yourself first) <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" /> will still bring a build error stated in the initial question, while: <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser " version="1.0.1" /> returns errors, (because the plugin name "cordova-plugin-inappbrowse" is invalid).   Meanwhile, the valid config xml syntax requires that you end the gap tag with "/>" not ">". In short, what i was saying is that: It'll be nicer, if you try the solution before answering.

Comment: If the option did not work for you, I don't care. You are not the person with the question. If you are the person with the question, you need to login with the correct name. If you are NOT the person the with the question, you need to start a new question. You CANNOT hijack another person's question and post. end of discussion.

Comment: Good explanation Jesse but you forgot to specify the source: `source="npm"`

Comment: When I gave the anwer, the answer was valide. The use is required when using the new plugin-name syntax. I did **UPDATE** the answer with a link AT THE TOP OF MY ORIGINAL ANSWER. If you have an issue understanding English, there is not much I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it happened to me too, and i'm YET to find a perfect solution till now;
so i just switched back to version 3.7 (pending the time); 
by updating the config.xml with:`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`  At least it serves the purpose and everything works.

Comment: Just a note:  For those who give up and revert back to 3.7.0, if you change the PG/cordova version in the config.xml you need to delete the App on your device and reinstall.  I have forgotten this before and been pulling my hair out.